# Substitution rule for the surface measure on a $C^1$-submanifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surface-integrals, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $\Omega$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. Assume, for simplicity, that $\Omega$ is described by a single chart, i.e. there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^k$.

Remember the definition of the surface measure $$\sigma_\Omega:=\phi^{-1}_\ast\left(\det\left|{\rm D}\phi^{-1}\right|\left.\lambda^{\otimes k}\right|_U\right),$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $|A|:=\sqrt{A^\ast A}$ for any matrix $A$.

Now let $T$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$. It's easy to see that $\Omega':=T(\Omega)$ is again a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ and $\phi':=\phi\circ\left.T^{-1}\right|_{\Omega'}$ is a chart for $\Omega'$.

> If $f:\Omega'\to\mathbb R$ is $\sigma_{\Omega'}$-integrable, are we able to show that $$\int f\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\Omega'}=\int_U\det\left|{\rm D}{\phi'}^{-1}\right|\left(f\circ{\phi'}^{-1}\right){\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes k}=\int_U\det\left|{\rm D}\phi^{-1}\right|\left(g\circ\phi^{-1}\right){\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes k}\tag1$$ for some $\sigma_\Omega$-integrable $g:\Omega\to\mathbb R$?

Note that ${\phi'}^{-1}=T\circ\phi^{-1}$ and $${\rm D}{\phi'}^{-1}(u)={\rm D}T\left(\phi^{-1}(u)\right){\rm D}\phi^{-1}(u)\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U.\tag2$$

Clearly, it's tempting to choose $g:=\left.\left|\det{\rm D}T\right|(f\circ T)\right|_\Omega$, but it seems like this choice doesn't yield the claim, when $k<d$.

> If $k=d$, it's easy to solve this issue, since we are then able to write $$\det\left|{\rm D}{\phi'}^{-1}(u)\right|=\left|\det{\rm D}{\phi'}^{-1}(u)\right|=\left|\det{\rm D}T\left(\phi^{-1}(u)\right)\right|\left|\det{\rm D}\phi^{-1}(u)\right|\tag3$$ for all $u\in U$ and hence $$\int f\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\Omega'}=\int\left|\det{\rm D}T\right|(f\circ T){\rm d}\sigma_\Omega\tag4.$$
>
> So, are we only able to find a transformation formula in the case $k=d$?

Comment: You should not expect a simpler formula. The natural change of variables formula kicks in when there is a diffeomorphism of the open set in $\Bbb R^k$. You can convince yourself that it's hopeless by considering a linear submanifold $\Omega$ and various linear maps $T\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ which either stretch $\Omega$ (and leave the orthogonal complement unaltered) or fix $\Omega$ (and act nontrivially on the orthogonal complement).

Comment: I should add a comment that the most natural solution to this problem is to represent the integral over $\Omega$ as the integral of a differential $k$-form $\eta$, and then the integral over $\Omega'$ will be the integral of the pullback $(T^{-1})^*\eta$.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean by "expecting a simpler formula"? I don't want to obtain a simpler formula, but prove the formula $(1)$ (or $(4)$) in the case $k<d$. I'm only able to prove it for $k=d$.

Comment: You're going to have to have the Gram determinant of the product $DT(\phi^{-1}(u))D\phi^{-1}(u)$, and that won't simplify in any way in general.

Comment: @TedShifrin So, there will be no function $g$ satisfying $(1)$, unless $k=d$, right?

Comment: Correct. Did you try doing my suggested "it's hopeless" exercise explicitly?

Comment: @TedShifrin Not yet. With "linear submanifold" you mean a submanifold which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Does the situation change, when $\Omega=\partial M$ for some $k$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary? In that case, we should obtain a formula $$\int f\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\Omega'}=\int\left|\det{\rm D}T\right|\left\|\left(\left({\rm D}T\right)^{-1}\right)^\ast\nu_\Omega\right\|(f\circ T)\:{\rm d}\sigma_\Omega$$ (I've only checked this for $k=d$, but even in that case we have obtained a formula even though $\Omega$ does not have codimension $0$ ($1$ here)).

Comment: Again, the case $k=d$ is entirely special. And it can probably be easily deduced along the lines I suggested by pulling back the appropriate $(d-1)$-form.

Comment: @TedShifrin But, as I've remarked in my last comment, it also holds in the case $k=d-1$, when $\Omega$ is the boundary of another submanifold with boundary. Regarding your "pullback" approach: I'm, unfortunately, not familiar with the concept differential forms.