# How can we show that $\det(A^TA)=\det(AA^T)$ for non-square $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$. Can we show that $\det(A^TA)=\det(AA^T)$?

If $m=n$, the answer is trivially yes, since then $\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\det A=\det^2A=\det(AA^T)$.

For the case $m=3$, $n=2$, I've checked the equality by a direction calculation and it actually holds true. So, I think this can be shown in general. But how?

Comment: You cannot. Take for instance $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Something slightly weaker holds: for non-square *real* $A$, (not counting multiplicity) the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ and $AA^T$ agree except possibly for $0$.

Comment: However, ranks coincide, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n

Comment: More simply, $A=(1\;\;0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Try even a $n\times 1$ example. Then $A^\top A$ is $1\times 1$ and the determinant is nonzero, assuming $A\ne 0$. However, $AA^\top$ is $n\times n$ and has rank $1$, so $\det(AA^\top)=0$.

Comment: Hah I was about to add this to my comment. $+1$ :)

Comment: Well, it seems like you're right. I was trying to find a suitable formula which I could use to find a substitution rule for surface integrals. Based on your background, you might know the answer. Could you please take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3836020/47771.